# How to initialize an void* pointer from struct

Tags: c, struct, void-pointers

I have a `struct Element`. When I try to initialize the elements array to `NULL`,
I get the  error: *incompatible types when assigning to type `Element` from type `void *`*.

How to initialize the `void *` array?

```
typedef struct _Element Element;
struct _Element {
    void* data;
};

typedef struct _ArrayList ArrayList;
struct _ArrayList {
    int size;
    Element *elements;
};

int main() {
    ArrayList *list;
    list->size = 100;
    list->elements = (Element*)calloc(sizeof(Element), list->size);

    for (i = 0; i < list->size; i++) {
        /*
         * error: incompatible types when assigning to type 
         * ‘Element’ from type ‘void *’
         */
        list->elements[i] = NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that `_Element` is a reserved identifier and should not be used.  Per [**7.1.3 Reserved identifiers** of the C11 standard](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.3): "All identifiers that begin with an underscore and either an uppercase letter or another underscore are always reserved for any use." and "All identifiers that begin with an underscore are always reserved for use as identifiers with file scope in both the ordinary and tag name spaces."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you never allocated memory for your `list` object! Your `list` pointer is uninitialized and points nowhere. Trying to apply the `->` operator to it causes undefined behavior.

I don't know what your final intent is, but it should be either something like

```
ArrayList *list = malloc(sizeof *list);
list->size = 100;
...
```

or

```
ArrayList list;
list.size = 100;
...
```

Secondly, your `void *` pointer is actually a named field called `data` inside `Element` struct

```
for(i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
    list->elements[i].data = NULL;
```

Thirdly, becuse you used `calloc` the memory is already sort of "initialized" with all-zero bit-pattern (including your `data` fileds). Formally, such bit-pattern in `void *` is not guaranteed to represent a null pointer, but on most platforms it actually does.

P.S. Don't cast the result of `calloc`

```
 list->elements = calloc(sizeof(Element), list->size);
```

or event better

```
 list->elements = calloc(sizeof *list->elements, list->size);
```

Comment: great answer! I am wandering if you initialize the list->elements = calloc(sizeof *list->elements, list->size); why is sizeof *list->elements? You mean sizeof (list->elements)?

Comment: great answer! I am wandering if you initialize the list->elements = calloc(sizeof *list->elements, list->size); why is sizeof *list->elements? You mean sizeof (list->elements)?

Comment: No, it should be `sizeof *list->elements` specifically (or `sizeof list->elements[0]`, which is the same thing). `sizeof list->elements` will give you *pointer* size, which is not what we need. We need *element* size.

Comment: @user1323328: Note that it is OK to use `*list->elements` under `sizeof` even when `list->elements` is not initialized yet. Sizeof argument in this case is not evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from all the logical errors, the compiler error is the result of trying to assign a value (NULL) to a struct-typed variable. The fact that the struct contains a `void *` is coincidental. You'd get the same error with:

```
typedef struct _Element Element;
struct _Element{
    int data;
};

Element e;
e = NULL;
```

This is most likely a mistake from what you intended to do, which is assign a value to the variable *inside* the struct:

```
for(i = 0; i < list->size; i++)
        list->elements[i].data = NULL;
```